# Почему знак процента (%) был выбран для спецификатора формата в функциях семейства printf?

Tags: c, история

Каждый знает, что, по крайней мере, в C для форматированного вывода строк используются функции семейства `printf`. Для обозначения начала *спецификатора формата* эти функции используют [знак процента](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) (%). Например, `%d` означает «напечатать `int`», `%u` означает «напечатать `unsigned int`». Если вы незнакомы с тем, как работают функция `printf` и спецификаторы формата, начните с [этой статьи в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf).

Мой вопрос заключается в том, **есть ли веская причина, по которой для обозначения начала спецификатора формата изначально был выбран знак процента? Следует ли нам и в дальнейшем придерживаться этого «правила»?**

Очевидно, что решение было принято очень давно (скорее всего даже предшественником языка C) и с тех пор стало, можно сказать, «стандартом» (не только в C, но и во многих других языках, которые в той или иной мере унаследовали его синтаксис), так что уже поздно что-то менять. Но мне все еще интересно, почему изначально было принято такое решение и стоит ли нам придерживаться его и в дальнейшем.

Например, в C# (и в других языках семейства .NET), разработчики из Microsoft приняли немного другое решение относительно форматированных строк. Они решили использовать фигурные кавычки с индексом аргумента:

```
string output = String.Format("In {0}, the temperature is {1} degrees Celsius.",
                              "Texas", 37);
Console.WriteLine(output);

// Output:
//     In Texas, the temperature is 37 degrees Celsius.
```

[Документация к методу `String.format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) содержит больше информации, как и [статья по составному форматированию в целом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting), но детали сейчас не особо важны. Важно, что разработчики отказались от использования `%` для обозначения начала спецификатора формата. Конечно, из за типобезопасности нам не нужно предоставлять никакой информации о типе соответствующего аргумента, в отличие от `printf` в C, но в C можно было бы просто использовать `{d}` и `{u}`. У кого-нибудь есть идеи, почему было принято иное решение? Следует ли нам и в дальнейшем придерживаться этой «традиции»?

Очевидно, что не существует экранируемого символа, который не мог бы быть использован сам по себе, но эта проблема уже решена использованием *двух* символов для управляющих последовательностей. Есть какие-нибудь другие соображения?

<sub>Перевод [этого](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159593/why-was-the-percent-sign-chosen-as-the-format-specifier-for-the-printf-famil) вопроса с SoftwareEngineering.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @Secure, при проектировании функции `printf` создатели языка C вдохновлялись функцией `writef` языка BCPL. Если взглянуть на [страницу BCPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL) в Википедии, можно найти пример, показывающий, что функция `writef` также использовала `%` для обозначения начала спецификатора формата.

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что C использует `%`, потому что тот же знак использовал BCPL. Мне кажется, такой выбор был сделан просто потому что `%` — это один из самых редко используемых символов ASCII… по крайней мере, так думали авторы. Похоже, они не долго взвешивали все «за» и «против». В то же время, и дизайн C и дизайн BCPL был довольно расплывчат, поэтому у авторов были более серьезные проблемы.

Однако здесь возникает неожиданная проблема. В то время как C был вдохновлен BCPL, не совсем ясно, то ли C заимствовал библиотеки ввода/вывода BCPL, то ли наоборот. Я смутно припоминаю, что библиотеки ввода/вывода BCPL эволюционировали примерно в то время, когда в язык был добавлен инфиксный оператор индексации байтов. (Думаю, я знаю, кто может дать точный ответ на этот вопрос.)

<sub>Перевод [ответа](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/159603/125896) пользователя [Stephen C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/172/stephen-c).</sub>

Comment: Теперь интересно было бы узнать что же так правильно заметил Secure? =)

Comment: @vp_arth, то что авторы C вдохновлялись функцией `writef` из BCPL :) Второй ответ по-сути идентичен этому.

Comment: [C's printf has its origins in BCPL's writef function (1966)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)